# AspNetCore - 400 When Extra Invalid Query Parameters Provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to validate the query parameters in the request to return a 400 (or other) status code when a query parameter that is not bindable/exposed in the MVC runtime is provided in the request. AKA: user provides a query parameter that is not defined.

I know this is easy to do with an ActionFilter that checks the Parameters property of the ActionDescriptor. There are a couple of SO questions and answers on this. **This only works when the query parameters are defined in the Controller's Action method.**

We are using a **single request model** that contains the route and query parameters within said request model class (to use Mediatr/CQS). We also have the Infer bindings behaviour off:

```
options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true
```

How can we validate the request's query parameters with what is bindable in the action?

---

Request model usage in Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [SwaggerOperation("Gets examples.", "Queries the example resources.")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Server error.", typeof(ProblemDetails), ContentTypes = new[] { "application/problem+json" })]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request.", typeof(ProblemDetails), ContentTypes = new[] { "application/problem+json" })]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, "Invalid request.", typeof(ProblemDetails), ContentTypes = new[] { "application/problem+json" })]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success.", typeof(Paginated<ExampleDto>))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(PaginatedExamplesExample))]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetExamplesAsync(GetExamplesQuery request, CancellationToken cancelToken) => HandleAsync(request, cancelToken);
```

Request Model:

```
public abstract record PaginatedQuery<TItem> : IPaginatedQuery<TItem>
{
    [FromQuery]
    public virtual string? SortBy { get; init; }

    [FromQuery]
    public virtual OrderBy? OrderBy { get; init; }

    [FromQuery]
    public virtual int? PageIndex { get; init; }

    [FromQuery]
    public virtual int? PageSize { get; init; }
}
```

Thus- if the user provides a query parameter that is not bindable to the request object(s) properties with FromQuery attributes, or Controller Action method parameters, return 400.

Comment: You should be getting an exception and you can return the 400 in the exception : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng extra query parameters will not cause an exception to be thrown in asp.net core so your link isn't relevant (it's also for asp.net 4)

Comment: A thought: could you iterate over HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys and return BadRequest if any elements don't match your named parameters?

Comment: @Luke I can, but i can't find a way to get all of the bindable properties for the action. the ActionDescriptor.Properties only has the Action's parameters (aka the controller method's parameters). But i think it's possible with some reflection. i was hoping to rely on some existing mechanism such as the binding in order to not perform reflection again.

Comment: Yeah, reflection will have a small impact on performance but I can't think of another way.